# Where did the vote for close as spam option go?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, flagging, spam

I was sure we had "flag as spam" and vote to close as spam options, but they seem to have gone.

I'm only as concerned, as I see a few obvious supplement blogspam posters come and go, and I feel a fitness Q&A board is likely to get a few non-reputable posts now and then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just flag things as spam, because you don't want to "close" spam, you want to destroy it